# Python histogram output with both try AND except code in output

Tags: python, matplotlib, exception

I'm looping over a pandas data frame (featuring string format data only) to create a histogram for each column.

I'm handling for exceptions, as I don't expect all columns to feature data that can be represented in a histogram.

The problem is that when I run the below code, for the 5 columns in my dataset I get a total of 4 histograms AND 5 of my custom error message.

What's going on? Also, the histograms don't have any titles, which they should.

Thanks!

```
# PACKAGES 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# DATA
data = {'col1': ['id345', 'id873', 'id972', 'id472', 'id930'],
        'col2': ['1.0', '0.0', '1.0', '0.0', np.nan],
        'col3': ['0.281', '0.380', '0.240', '0.260', '0.222'],
        'col4': ['0.17', '0.184', '0', '0.22', np.nan],
        'col5': ['1', '1', '0', np.nan, '0']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])


# HISTOGRAMS
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    try:
        pd.to_numeric(df[col]).hist(fig=plt.figure(i))
        plt.title(col)
    except:
        print('My error message')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `plt.figure(i)` which is a figure instance and `pd.Series.hist()` does not know how to handle such. You can do:

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    try:
        # try to convert to numeric first
        # if this fails, error is thrown and jump to `Except`
        s = pd.to_numeric(df[col])

        # create an axis instance and pass to `hist`
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        s.hist(ax=ax)
        plt.title(col)

    except:
        print('My error message')
```

And you should get just one error message.

Comment: In my output I see one error message. Great, expected it for col1. But I don't see any histograms, which I expect for col2, col3, col4, and col5. Do I need to do something else to actually view the histograms (I haven't created plots much in python)? Thanks